# Exporting and importing calendar data using C#

Tags: c#, calendar

I have a database of calendar events and dates.  What is the best way of exporting this to common formats ("ics" for example) using c#.  Are there common libraries to use?

Also, are there any good libraries for importing "ics" formats as well.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/bradvincent/archive/2008/01/16/creating-vcalendars-programmatically.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one it sounds promising:

[DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/)